# How can i disable/enable select option based on radio button with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i disable/enable select option by clicking radio button with JavaScript?

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-4 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">durian
    </label>
    <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <input type="radio" class="radio-button" name="fruit">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-11">
            <select id="durian" class="form-control" style="width: 100%" name="durian">
                <option value="pilih" disabled selected>Pilih</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-4 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">starfruit
    </label>
    <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <input type="radio" class="radio-button" name="fruit">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-11">
            <select id="starfruit" class="form-control" style="width: 100%" name="starfruit">
                <option value="pilih" disabled selected>Pilih</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Sorry for my bad English. This is my first post. Hope you can help me. Thanks

Comment: can you add what you have tried so far?

Comment: Why do your `<select>` elements only have one `<option>` each? (I encourage cutting down to a minimal example for inclusion in a question, but that seems to be going too far...)

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Laravel. Tag removed.

Comment: @guradio i just do some research on google and try in jsfidle , btw thanks for editting my post

Comment: @slick thanks sir for edit my post too

Comment: sry bad english guys :p lol

Comment: Possible duplicate of [enable disable select / dropdown on radio selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37346081/enable-disable-select-dropdown-on-radio-selection)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var $radio = $('input[name="fruit"]');
var $durianSelect = $('#durian');
var $starSelect = $("#starfruit");

$starSelect.prop('disabled', true);
$radio.on('change', function(e) {
 if ($(this).val() === 'durian') {
    $starSelect.prop('disabled', true);
    $durianSelect.prop('disabled', false)
 } else {
    $starSelect.prop('disabled', false);
    $durianSelect.prop('disabled', true);
 }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-4 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">durian
    </label>
    <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <input type="radio" class="radio-button" name="fruit" value="durian" checked>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-11">
            <select id="durian" class="form-control" style="width: 100%" name="durian">
                <option value="pilih" disabled selected>Pilih</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-4 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">starfruit
    </label>
    <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <input type="radio" class="radio-button" name="fruit" value="starfruit">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-11">
            <select id="starfruit" class="form-control" style="width: 100%" name="starfruit">
                <option value="pilih" disabled selected>Pilih</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: sir can i ask ? what its that mean function(e) ?

Comment: e is the DOM event object returned by browser, is the default param.

Comment: sir , i have problem , when i use i check the code not working , can u tell me why ?       $('input').iCheck({
      checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_flat-blue',
      radioClass: 'iradio_flat-blue'
    });

Comment: BTW  you help me so much , thanks sir , sry bad english :p

Comment: The configs `checkboxClass` and  `radioClass` of `$('input')`  is the base class added to customized checkboxes and radio buttons respectly, for example, you radios should have the class: `<input type="radio" class="iradio_flat-blu radio-button" />`.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one

you can make condition for every id use the function

```
    `https://jsfiddle.net/h34cp3gu/`
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(function() {
    $('.radio-button').on('change',function() {
        var pilih = $(this).val();
        $('select').not('#'+pilih).prop('disabled',true);
        $('#'+pilih).prop('disabled',false);
    });
});
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ot5eq4ug/

Comment: makasih mas taufik :v

Comment: iya sama sama :3